# Is there some way to test iPhone app without using any tool?

Tags: iphone

I want to test iPhone app for images , button clicks,menu navigation ,  pass some values.
Is there some way to test it without using any tool.

Comment: without any tool or emulator, only I-phone itself is the option available.

Comment: Take a paper, draw your UI as in your app, simulate the series of actions using your own drawings. If you succeed in doing that, I am sure, you are the best iPhone developer in the world. (Note: No offense.. Just kidding..).

Comment: either simulator or iPhone itself.thats all

Comment: You use a tool to write your iPhone app, why can't you use a tool for testing it?

Comment: Ok i meant if there is something inbuilt in xcode to do the automation. or by writing some scripts using xcode we can test the app. is it possible ??

Comment: @Simon: are you sure you're just kidding? [Paper prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_prototyping) can be a very valuable tool, even in [iPhone development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4v3chsNReo). The [Hanmail.net webmail paper prototype](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrV2SZuRPv0) is particularly well-done.

Comment: @outis: Paper prototyping is cool if he is going to develop an app.. Do you think this will really help him in testing.. I don't think he will draw the output of all possible changes for each and every line of code.. I am sure he will give up app development and will go to comics development :)

Comment: @Simon: it would help in usability testing. Your comment may not be what OQ had in mind, but it answered the question shklee asked. Caveat suppliciter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no scripts for making test-cases in xcode, so there is no supported way to write any automatic test system (or I don't know any).

If You want, You may use Mac Os's Automator script with xcode and iPhone simulator.